# Clearing floats in IE7 without breaking up text flow

Tags: html, css, css-float, internet-explorer-7

Please reference the following [example](http://jsfiddle.net/bHKFD/26/):

Requirements:

- Have one element floated right.
- Have another element clear first, and floated left.
- Have text flow and wrap all floated elements.

This seems like a dead simple example of using floats in a layout, and yet there seems like no possible way to do it in IE7.

In the given example, IE7 doesn't respect the clear, and both elements float to the top:

```
    <!-- Floated blocks -->
<div style="float:right; display:block; background:#FF0000; width:200px; height:100px;" ></div>
<div style="float:left; clear:right; display:block; background:#FF0000; width:200px; height:100px;" ></div>
    <!-- Wrapping text -->
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a nisi tellus. Ut ac iaculis erat. Integer nec turpis mi, quis placerat eros. Donec suscipit eros vel nulla vulputate cursus. Aenean ut augue nisi, a sagittis velit. Mauris eget velit at felis feugiat consequat. Sed interdum lobortis porttitor. Vestibulum ultrices posuere ipsum id posuere.</p>
<p>Nam imperdiet, orci sed faucibus tempus, arcu est pretium mauris, in mollis tellus augue imperdiet elit. Maecenas mi nunc, rhoncus in feugiat et, varius at lacus. Etiam at iaculis libero. Phasellus eu ipsum tortor. Maecenas non purus dolor. Suspendisse risus felis, varius et porttitor eu, ultricies a orci. Nullam ac ipsum diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed convallis suscipit eros consequat sollicitudin. </p> 
<p>Morbi facilisis aliquet rutrum. Vestibulum dignissim neque velit. Nunc auctor, ante nec placerat commodo, metus felis dignissim metus, sit amet aliquet sem nisi eget neque. Morbi diam massa, porttitor ac egestas at, bibendum id mauris. Phasellus at leo at est lobortis ullamcorper at vel dolor. Suspendisse tincidunt lobortis quam a luctus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris id metus id mauris rhoncus adipiscing ac quis arcu. Phasellus magna lectus, venenatis non tempor id, euismod ut quam.</p>
<p>Vivamus gravida dui ut dui facilisis ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Nunc eu sagittis ante. Fusce sit amet velit vel lacus congue sodales. Integer sollicitudin varius orci. Sed tellus erat, porttitor a ultricies nec, pellentesque nec felis. Sed at arcu ipsum. Etiam lorem leo, egestas et euismod nec, rhoncus dictum mauris. Fusce vestibulum lectus eget magna sollicitudin vulputate pulvinar augue tempus. Integer urna lacus, tincidunt eget fermentum eu, condimentum et eros. Ut vitae tortor porttitor dui elementum sollicitudin nec a ante.</p>
```

I'm open to ANY solution that enables the intended layout.  Thanks--

Comment: @Kevin- code is included

Comment: Can you send a picture of how the layout should be?, not sure what are you trying to accomplish.

Comment: @omabena- Please follow the example link- it's right there if you view it in a non-IE7 browser.  In IE7, however, the two red boxes will both be all the way to the top.

Comment: @Yarin, I edited your question to include the code here. Segmenting it to other sites is frowned upon.

Comment: @Kevin- That's fine, but we use JS Fiddle a lot around here to trade and test code versions- stuff we can't do within SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your blocks have a fixed height, you can float a 0 width div with the same height as the div floated to the right.

```
<div style="float:right; display:block; background:#FF0000; width:200px; height:100px;" ></div>
<div style="float:left; display:block; background:transparent; width:0; height:100px;" >&nbsp;</div>
<div style="float:left; clear:both; display:block; background:#FF0000; width:200px; height:100px;" ></div>
```

Comment: +1 very nice and so simple.. although I found the 0 width didn't work, I changed the "fake" div to `1px` wide and removed the `&nbsp;` :) - actually hang on something's not lining up.. but I think this should work.. will check

Comment: :(.. ackk... it appears to only work (or some of the text gets hidden by floats, half if lines etc.) if the [`vertical rhythm`](http://drewish.com/tools/vertical-rhythm) is strictly controlled.. for example in the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/c4SDh/) - I made the line height and margins of the `p` 20px so the float height - 100px should always clear, it wouldn't always be possible to do that if there's headings etc. (btw the lime green is for visual only)

Comment: This is actually the answer I came up with as well - best we can hope for I guess- thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible I'm afraid :(

see [here](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEWfc3.html) for lots of test cases that specifically point out where IE7 fails, if there was a solution Bruno would link to it, I'm sure. btw that page leads to another with even more

in short :

**`clear: both` (or the direction) will fail unless the previous float is is the same direction**

I've had a look a round and the only solution for some cases is to add an extra element between the floats, but that won't work in your case as it will push the text below the bottom of the inserted element

I can't even think of a way to mimic it with script

Comment: @clairesuzy- thanks for the clarification and good link.  Can't believe I haven't brushed up against this issue before!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but this looks "OK" in my IE browser:

```
    <p><div style="float:right; display:block; background:#FF0000; width:200px; height:100px;" ></div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque a nisi tellus. Ut ac iaculis erat. Integer nec turpis mi, quis placerat eros. Donec suscipit eros vel nulla vulputate cursus. Aenean ut augue nisi, a sagittis velit. Mauris eget velit at felis feugiat consequat. Sed interdum lobortis porttitor. Vestibulum ultrices posuere ipsum id posuere.</p>

    <div style="float:left; clear:right; display:block; background:#FF0000; width:200px; height:100px;" ></div><p>Nam imperdiet, orci sed faucibus tempus, arcu est pretium mauris, in mollis tellus augue imperdiet elit. Maecenas mi nunc, rhoncus in feugiat et, varius at lacus. Etiam at iaculis libero. Phasellus eu ipsum tortor. Maecenas non purus dolor. Suspendisse risus felis, varius et porttitor eu, ultricies a orci. Nullam ac ipsum diam. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Sed convallis suscipit eros consequat sollicitudin. </p> 
    <p>Morbi facilisis aliquet rutrum. Vestibulum dignissim neque velit. Nunc auctor, ante nec placerat commodo, metus felis dignissim metus, sit amet aliquet sem nisi eget neque. Morbi diam massa, porttitor ac egestas at, bibendum id mauris. Phasellus at leo at est lobortis ullamcorper at vel dolor. Suspendisse tincidunt lobortis quam a luctus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris id metus id mauris rhoncus adipiscing ac quis arcu. Phasellus magna lectus, venenatis non tempor id, euismod ut quam.</p>
<p>Vivamus gravida dui ut dui facilisis ullamcorper. Nulla facilisi. Nunc eu sagittis ante. Fusce sit amet velit vel lacus congue sodales. Integer sollicitudin varius orci. Sed tellus erat, porttitor a ultricies nec, pellentesque nec felis. Sed at arcu ipsum. Etiam lorem leo, egestas et euismod nec, rhoncus dictum mauris. Fusce vestibulum lectus eget magna sollicitudin vulputate pulvinar augue tempus. Integer urna lacus, tincidunt eget fermentum eu, condimentum et eros. Ut vitae tortor porttitor dui elementum sollicitudin nec a ante.</p>
```

The problem is that the code above is **not HTML valid**, because you aren't allowed to put a block element inside an inline element. As mentioned above, it's probably not possible to do it on a HTML-valid-way.

Comment: @Bart- Your example completely changes the layout- it's dividing up the text within the float blocks- I want the text to wrap around the floated elements like the example shows.

Comment: @Bart- Thanks, the second part actually works in IE, though I agree it's almost too invalid to attempt in good faith.  (PS If you delete the first part of your answer I can plus 1 you)

Comment: I deleted the first part. Thank you. :)